# Adding a custom drop down to highstock range selector menu

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to add custom drop down button as following image to highchart. I tried adding custom button as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/2F4pJ/), but it doesn't provide a way to add drop down above the chart. any one know a correct method.

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            customButton: {
                x: -150,
                onclick: function () {
                    alert('Clicked');
                },
                symbol: 'circle'
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use HTML select with defined CSS styles, like position absolute and top/left.

Comment: Can you please explain it little bit. I tried to get elementbyClassName and append html button. But it doesn't work

Comment: I mean using <select></select> tag in html, which is placed absolutely. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7v2bwv5u/2/

Comment: wow it works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML select with defined CSS styles, like position absolute and top/left. I mean using  tag in html, which is placed absolutely.

HTML:

```
<div class="chart">
<select>
    <option>OHLC</option>
    <option>Candlestick</option>
</select>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width:750px;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart {
position:relative;
}
.chart select {
    position:absolute;
    right:50%;
    top:45px;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7v2bwv5u/2